# How can I convert a HEIC file to a JPEG file, in Debian?

Tags: linux, conversion, gimp, jpeg

This question appears to address this https://askubuntu.com/questions/958355/any-app-on-ubuntu-to-open-and-or-convert-heif-pictures-heic-high-efficiency-i

However, on Debian, adding the required repository fails:

```
# add-apt-repository ppa:strukturag/libheif
 This PPA contains packages to add support for HEIC / HEIF files.

HEIF is a new image file format employing HEVC (h.265) image coding for the best compression ratios currently possible.

libheif is an ISO/IEC 23008-12:2017 HEIF file format decoder (encoder to come). It makes use of libde265 for the actual image decoding. Alternative codecs for, e.g., AVC and JPEG can be provided as plugins.

libheif has support for
- tiled images
- alpha channels
- thumbnails
- reading EXIF data
- reading the depth channel
- multiple images in a HEIF file
- image transformations (crop, mirror, rotate)
- overlay images
- plugin interface to add decoders for additional formats (AVC, JPEG)

See https://github.com/strukturag/libheif for further information.

NOTE: You will also need to enable the PPA "strukturag/libde265"
if you are running Ubuntu Trusty or older, so dependencies can be
resolved.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~strukturag/+archive/ubuntu/libheif
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmp5zlukp3z/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: key 9641080A705C2B92: 12 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: /tmp/tmp5zlukp3z/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 9641080A705C2B92: public key "Launchpad PPA for struktur AG" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 688, in addkey_func
    func(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 386, in add_key
    return apsk.add_ppa_signing_key()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 273, in add_ppa_signing_key
    cleanup(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 234, in cleanup
    shutil.rmtree(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 480, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 438, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 436, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(name, dir_fd=topfd)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'S.gpg-agent.extra'
```

Hence I can't use this approach.

Is there any other way? I simply want to convert a set of HEIC files to JPEG from the command line. In a pinch, I could start up GIMP and manually convert them one by one. However, even GIMP fails to read this format.

Comment: Have you [looked at this thread](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/91640/how-can-i-convert-an-apple-ios-heif-image-into-jpeg)?

Comment: libheif is in Debian Stable - is there a specific reason why you want to get it from somewhere else?